# Prevent row delete if column is referenced to another table PHP | Laravel | mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm creating a stock management system (hobby project) on Laravel. But I have a few tables like stock, device_type, locations etc. On the 'stocks' table, there's a field called 'device_type_id' which reference to 'id' on 'device_type' table. I want to configure the 'device_type' table in a way, that any row in 'device_type' table can not be deleted if 'id' of 'device_type' table matches with any 'device_type_id' on 'stocks' table. Any advice?

**'stocks' table migration**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('device_type_id');
        $table->string('make');
        $table->string('model');
        $table->string('spec');
        $table->string('condition');
        $table->string('suk')->nullable();
        $table->date('purchase_date');
        $table->string('inv')->nullable();
        $table->string('location');
        $table->string('assigned_to');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('device_type')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('device_type');
    });
}
```

**'device_type' table migration**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('device_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('device_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create device_type table migration then create stocks table migration.

And in stocks table migration write foreign key as follows:

```
$table->foreign('device_type_id')->references('id')->on('device_type');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listner for deleting a type and check if the type is referenced then don't delete it else you can delete it :

in the **DeviceType** model add this method :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($type) {
        // assuming you have stocks relationship in your DeviceType model
        if ($type->stocks()->count() > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```